# Como criar "desenhos" em arquivos escritos em Batch

Tags: batch, cmd

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Como faço para adicionar "desenhos" no meu código .bat iguais aqueles que aparecem no Terminal do Linux?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei inserir o "desenho" utilizando a ferramenta FIGlet Generator.
Porém quando executo o arquivo (código fonte) para abrir no Prompt de Comandos do Windows o mesmo abre e fecha em uma velocidade muito rápida.
Mesmo com o comando Pause>nul o mesmo não permanece aberto.
Sendo assim não consigo ver o erro.

Acredito que esteja ocorrendo talvez pelo uso do caractere |
o qual já está reservado para comandos (Sendo assim a sintaxe estaria errada).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Isto é conhecido como **ASCII art** (um termo vulgar/comum), não quer dizer que é um termo oficial, o básico dele é você escrever mesmo baseado em caracteres da tabela ASCII para "simular" um desenho, não é bem um problema de programação, no entanto a parte que cabe a programação é entender que é necessário usar este 2 comandos:

- `echo`
- `pause`

Usando essa ferramenta eu criei um texto http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Graffiti&t=Stack, obtive isto:

```
  _________ __                 __    
 /   _____//  |______    ____ |  | __
 \_____  \\   __\__  \ _/ ___\|  |/ /
 /        \|  |  / __ \\  \___|    < 
/_______  /|__| (____  /\___  >__|_ \
        \/           \/     \/     \/
```

No entanto note que caracteres como `<`, `>`, `|`, `&` devem ser escapados usado o sinal de `^`

Então deve ficar assim:

```
  _________ __                 __    
 /   _____//  ^|______    ____ ^|  ^| __
 \_____  \\   __\__  \ _/ ___\^|  ^|/ /
 /        \^|  ^|  / __ \\  \___^|    ^< 
/_______  /^|__^| (____  /\___  ^>__^|_ \
        \/           \/     \/     \/
```

Um exemplo de um arquivo `.bat` seria assim:

```
@echo off

echo   _________ __                 __
echo  /   _____//  ^|______    ____ ^|  ^| __
echo  \_____  \\   __\__  \ _/ ___^|  ^|/ /
echo  /        \^|  ^|  / __ \\  \___^|    ^<
echo /_______  /^|__^| (____  /\___  ^>__^|_ \
echo         \/           \/     \/     \/

pause
```

> **É importante** notar que o CMD padrão do Windows tem limite, se o texto ultrapassar este limite ele será quebrado para a linha seguinte (creio que o limite seja 80 caracteres, talvez mude em sistemas mais antigos)

Claro que algumas coisas terá que ajustar manualmente, mas não é tão complicado, veja o resultado:

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Caramba, ajudou muito!

Comment: Valeu!!! Obrigado.